# Swift4: Tab Bar layout issue, there is a blank bar

Tags: ios, layout, tabbar

As the following picture, from window.root to tabBarController, tabBarController's first child is a navigation Controller, the issue occurs in the root view controller of the navigation Controller.

[image]

Here is the issue:

When I call the bottom tab bar show and hide, the layout issues. A blank bar , which has size of tab bar, sucks.

[image: img]

Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var heading: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var username: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var password: UITextField!

    let tabBarViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        username.delegate = self
        password.delegate = self
    }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    tabBarViewController.tabBar.isHidden = true
  }
}


extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let nextField = (textField === username) ? password : username
    nextField?.becomeFirstResponder()

    if textField.text == "1" {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true )
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
        tabBarViewController.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
    else{
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true )
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
          tabBarViewController.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
    return true
}

}
```

I thought the layout options in size inspector maybe matters. I have not find any clue.

[image: imageTwo]

Any helpful tips, is quite welcomed.

Comment: Thx , Code intervene。 Just delete `navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(bool, animated: true)`    =。 =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hide ToolBar when the value is equal to 1:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
   func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      let nextField = (textField === username) ? password : username
      nextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
      if textField.text == "1" {
          self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true )
          navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
          tabBarViewController.tabBar.isHidden = false
     }else{
          self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true )
          navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
          tabBarViewController.tabBar.isHidden = true
     }
     return true
}
```